# Как получить записи, ID которых нет в массиве?

Tags: php

Есть массив **A** с ID записей и есть еще массив **B** с ID актуальных записей.

Нужно из массива **A** получить ID записей которых нет в массиве **B**.

Как правильно такое реализовать?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-diff.php ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
$a = array(1, 2, 5, 6, 10);
$b = array(2, 5, 6);
$result = array_diff($a, $b);

print_r($result);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [4] => 10
)
```